# jQuery - Find any input with a given class that has no value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a (very) basic validation script. I basically want to check for any inputs with class .required to see if there values are a) blank or b) 0 and if so, return false on my form submit. This code does not seem to return false:

```
function myValidation(){
  if($(".required").val() == "" || $(".required").val() == 0){
  $(this).css({ backgroundColor:'orange' })  ;
  return false;
  }
}
```

Appending this function to my onSubmit handler of my form is not returning any results. Any light shed on this matter will be appreciated.

I am basically after a function that iterates through all the inputs with class .required, and if ANY have blank or 0 values, return false on my submit and change the background colour of all badly behaved inputs to orange.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code currently gets the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for the *first* `.required`, from [the `.val()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/.):

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

You need to filter through each one individually instead, like this:

```
function myValidation(){
  var allGood = true;
  $(".required").each(function() {
     var val = $(this).val();
     if(val == "" || val == 0) {
       $(this).css({ backgroundColor:'orange' });
       allGood = false;
     }
  });
  return allGood;
}
```

Or a bit more compact version:

```
function myValidation(){
  return $(".required").filter(function() {
     var val = $(this).val();
     return val == "" || val == 0;
  }).css({ backgroundColor:'orange' }).length === 0;
}
```

Comment: I had to make a contribution one way or another :). No problemo.

Comment: Spot On, works like a bomb thanks. May be worth mentioning that it did not work as a function on the onSubmit action of the form, but when used as a straight set of checks attached to $("#myForm").submit(function(){ ..code above goes here ... }); it worked like a dream, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this jQuery selector:

```js
$('.required[value=""], .required[value=0]')
```

JS Documentation: [Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it by defining your own custom jQuery selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.extend($.expr[':'],{
        textboxEmpty: function(el){
            return ($(el).val() === "");
        }
    });
});
```

And then access them like this:

```
alert($('input.required:textboxEmpty').length); //alerts the number of input boxes in your selection
```

So you could put a `.each` on them:

```
$('input.required:textboxEmpty').each(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```