# How to find whether the class attribute is present or not in the input element using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to find the class name specified in the input attribute using jquery

```
<Html>
<body>
<input type="text" class="name"/>
</body>
</Html>
```

here how i can find the class name using jquery

Comment: use `hasClass()` https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/ `Description: Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.`

Comment: Your title and your question's body conflicts with the exact requirement

Comment: i want to get the class name ,i dont know what is the class name present for the element then how to find it?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400386/get-class-name-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Find any input with a given class that has no value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477311/jquery-find-any-input-with-a-given-class-that-has-no-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get class list for element with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) :-

```
$("input[type='text']").attr('class');
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/n0cfdxup/36/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input').hasClass('name') ? alert('has class name') : alert('has no class name')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="name"/>
```

use [.hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

> Description: Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var className = $('.name').attr('class');
alert(className);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="name"/>
```